# How to find percentage values of a column in sas?

Tags: sas

Friends,
In SAS how can we find percentage values of a column?
My data set output and its code is given below
[image]

and the code is

```
data out.calculate_age;                                                                                                                 
set out.calculate_age ;                                                                                                                 
if age = "" then age = "All";                                                                                                           
if d=. then d=0;                                                                                                                        
if s=. then s=0;                                                                                                                        
if i=. then i=0;                                                                                                                        
tot = d+s+i;     /*CALCULATING TOTAL NO. PER GROUP*/                                                                                    
PERCENTAGE=round((tot/sum(tot))*100,.1); /*PERCENTAGE PER GROUP*/                                                                       
run;
```

I want, in 'percentage' column, the values should be 8*100/(8+24+36+36+27) , 24*100/(8+24+36+36+27)  , 36*100/(8+24+36+36+27) etc... 
 I know sum(tot) is 8/8 , 24/24 etc...(Its calculating row wise)...

So what should I do to get right percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum up the counts for an overall total and put it into a macro variable:

```
proc sql ;
  select sum(d)+sum(i)+sum(s)
  into :N
  from input 
;quit ;
```

You can then reference this in your code:

```
data out.calculate_age;                                                                                                                 
set out.calculate_age ;                                                                                                                 
if age = "" then age = "All";                                                                                                           
if d=. then d=0;                                                                                                                        
if s=. then s=0;                                                                                                                        
if i=. then i=0;                                                                                                                        
tot = d+s+i;     /*CALCULATING TOTAL NO. PER GROUP*/                                                                                    
PERCENTAGE=round(tot/&N.,.1); /*PERCENTAGE PER GROUP*/                                                                       
run;
```